# Remote port blocking in firewalls?

Tags: security, firewall, ports

some guys use a firewall on their laptops which not only blocks their own *local* incoming ports (except those they need for their application) but also blocks messages unless they are issued *from* a distinct port number. We're talking about a local UDP server which is listening to UDP broadcasts.
The problem is that the remote client uses a random port, say 1024, which is blocked unless they tell the firewall to accept it.

What puzzles me is that as far as I know from using sockets in my programs is that usually the *client* gets its port number from the OS, whereas only when you have a server, you bind your socket to a distinct port, right?

In my literature and in tutorials and code snippets in the web I haven't found any clue that clients should be using fixed port numbers at all.

So how is this in reality? Am I probably missing a point?
Are there client applications around using fixed ports?
Is is actually *useful* to block *remote* ports with a firewall?
And if yes, what level of added security does this give to you?

Thanks for enlightenment in beforehand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the default API's allow the network stack to select a local port for client connections, clients may specify a fixed port for various reasons.

- Some specifications (FTP) specify a fixed port for clients.  Most servers don't care if clients get this correct.
- Some clients use a fixed pool of ports for egress from a LAN to the Internet.  This allows firewall rules to more completely lock down outbound traffic.
- Source ports are sometimes uses as a weak type of "security through obscurity".

Comment: Thanks Darron. To give you a more detailed picture: The clients are embedded devices and the laptops are from the service department which occasionally connect to the devices. I am writing the client's software. 
So my concern is that I must somehow tell my socket class to bind to a port number which I am rather reluctant to do since I feel that's quite unusual. Or I somehow need to tell the OS/network stack to narrow down the range of usable ports.

Answer (score 0):

You always get a random address and/or port when not explicitly having bound to one before sending.

Daemons are *usually* bound to a fixed port, so that:

- you can actually contact them without having to try all possible ports or utilize a secondary resolver (remember the SUNRPC portmapping crap?)
- and because a TCP socket is not allowed to listen() if it has not bound to a port, IIRC.

> Are there client applications around using fixed ports?

Some can be configured so, like BIND9.

> useful to block remote ports with a firewall?

No, because your peer may choose any port of his. Block him and you'll lose a customer, so to speak.

Comment: Concerning servers/deamons it is quite obvious, how else would one connect to them. ;-) OK, I just read some essay on "Port knocking", quite interesting stuff but seems to be only for very specialised client/server pairs.
I am just wondering why the point "client sockets with fixed port" is not touched in programming tutorials. If I'd known that this is an option in the "network world", I wouldn't be surprised. That's why I asked if it is done at all. (please see as well my comments I wrote to Darron's answer)